# ODETTE FTP (OFTP) for .NET or Delphi

Tags: c#, .net, delphi, ftp

I'm trying to come up with a proposal for a client for an interface with a European Automotive manufacturer. The standard interface to transfer data files(EDIFAC) is [ODETTE-FTP](http://www.rfc-archive.org/getrfc.php?rfc=2204) (OFTP).

I'm trying to find a native component solution, much like what's available for other FTP formats. After much Google searching I haven't been able to find that solution. IP*Works has a BizTalk add in, and there is an open source Java project is all I've turned up.

Anyone have any good leads on this? Having to roll my own OFTP solution from scratch is going to put us outside the time/cost constraints of our client.

Comment: Nobody knows this stuff better than the IT staff of your customer.  They got to keep it running.  Ask them.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm the IT staff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm the one that developed the open source Java project for Odette FTP. ACCORD is a project actually being developed by Neociclo under the OW2 Consortium, focused to bring a set of tools around the OFTP connectivity, but so far we've a stable OFTP2 component library that is being used around.

I would propose you to consider the tools from [www.iKVM.net](http://www.ikvm.net) and try creating a prototype for such interoperability between Java and .Net. If you find it's feasible or succeed in the prototype we can help you in setting up the component library to fit in your needs.

Get involved subscribing to accord-users@ow2.org mailing list.

Best regards,

Rafael Marins

Comment: Please, visit the site www.iKVM.net instead of the previously indicated.

Comment: Ended up go with a rvs to import the files and then parse them with our in house application. But I've accepted as the best answer for what was asked, thanks!